# How to censor a part of cventry with the censor package?

Tags: moderncv, compilation-error

I have to censor sensitive information in CVs. The CVs use the `moderncv` package. I decided to use the `censor` package to blackening the sensitive information. When I try to censor the third parameter in a `\cventry`, I encounter an error:

> *! Use of @@array doesn't match its definition.*

**The MWE**

```
%!TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[orange]{classic} % [color]{stye}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{censor}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}

\firstname{firstname}
\familyname{lastname}
\address{street}{postal code}
\email{e-mail}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Interests}
\cventry{Since 2000}{}{\censor{to be censored}}{Test}{}{}

\end{document}
```

**The error log**

> ! Use of @@array doesn't match its definition. @ifnextchar
>   \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f... l.26
>   ...2000}{}{\censor{to be censored}}{Test}{}{}
>
> If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always put`1' after
>   `\a', since control sequence names are made up of letters only. The
>   macro here has not been followed by the required stuff, so I'm
>   ignoring it.
>
> ! Argument of @firstoftwo has an extra }. \par  l.26
>   ...2000}{}{\censor{to be censored}}{Test}{}{}
>
> I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything. For
>   example,`\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce this error. If you
>   simply proceed now, the`\par' that I've just inserted will cause me
>   to report a runaway argument that might be the root of the problem.
>   But if your `}' was purious, just type`2' and it will go away.
>
> Runaway argument? ! Paragraph ended before @firstoftwo was complete.
>
> \par  l.26 ...2000}{}{\censor{to be censored}}{Test}{}{}
>
> I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control
>   equence to too much text. How can we recover? My plan is to forget the
>   whole thing and hope for the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\protect` before your command `\censor` to be able to compile the censored CV.

Please see this MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[orange]{classic} % [color]{stye}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{censor}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}

\name{firstname}{lastname}
\address{street}{postal code}
\email{e-mail}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Interests}
\cventry{Since 2000}{}{\protect\censor{to be censored}}{Test}{}{} % <=============

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting cv]